# Gruntfile settings for compiled .jade files

Tags: pug, gruntjs

In my Gruntfile I have

```
jade: {
  html: {
    expand: true,
    src: ['public/views/**/*.jade'],
    dest: '.tmp',
    ext: '.html'
  }
},
```

which does compile the .jade files to html, but includes the public/ directory, resulting in .tmp/public/views/foo.html, but I would like to have .tmp/views/foo.html, instead.

I have added an additional static path for express, which does allow for the public/**/*.html to be served back, but it would be nice to keep things clean.

Any ideas?

Comment: What grunt plugin you're using? `grunt-contrib-jade` doesn't have these options...

Comment: I believe he is using `grunt-contrib-jade`. I am using it in a very similar fashion and it works like a charm.

Comment: grunt-contrib-jade is what I am using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
jade: {
    html: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'public/',
            src: ['views/**/*.jade'],
            dest: '.tmp',
            ext: '.html'
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Nailed it!  I had found a snippet like that before, but for some reason it wasn't working for me, so I reverted to what I posted in the question.  Thanks for the help.